# How to remove the begining and ending characters if those are '0' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table named `DATA` it has entries like the following:

```
abc000
ab000cde
000abc
```

I just want to remove all 0 from beginning and the end. If 0 comes in between the character then it will remain same.

Comment: Do you always have three zeros at the beginning or the end ? or do the zeros have different lengths ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also works for leading and trailing zeros at the same time:

```
declare @s varchar(15) = '00abc00efg000'
select substring(@s, 
                 patindex('%[^0]%', @s), 
                 len(@s)-patindex('%[^0]%', reverse(@s))-patindex('%[^0]%', @s)+2);
```

Description: this is substring from first nonzero symbol till first nonzero symbol in reversed string.

Answer (score 2):

Say your data exists in column called `Col1`, then this expression should do it

```
select CASE 
           WHEN RIGHT(col1 , 1) = '0'
           THEN SUBSTRING(col1,0,PATINDEX('%[A-Z1-9]%',REVERSE(col1)))
           WHEN LEFT(col1 , 1) = '0'
           THEN SUBSTRING(col1,PATINDEX('%[A-Z1-9]%',col1),LEN(col1))
           ELSE 
            Col1 
        END AS 'ParsedCol1'
FROM Data
```

Comment: But This is not working when more than 3 zero comes before and after charctaers....

Answer (score 2):

I use this trick:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(col1, ' ', CHAR(8)), '0', ' '))), ' ', '0'), CHAR(8), ' ')
FROM 
    yourTable
```

Comment: Nice and will work for both leading and trailing zeros at the same time.

Comment: Nice Sir ! It's Great Answer !

Answer (score 0):

This  may  works for SQL, as this removes leading & trailing "000" from your string.

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ‘000’ FROM    
‘your_data_table_column’);
```

See more

http://www.mydigitallife.info/remove-or-trim-first-or-last-few-characters-in-mysql-database-with-sql/

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php

Comment: In SQL Server there is not `TRIM` ;).